# batch file remove files by the specified extension

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete all files with extensions which are not specified in the arguments (except .sys files). The problem is with an assignment of my variable.

Here are my commands (apologies for duplication, wasn't sure how to use or statement here):

```
@echo off
cls
cd test
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set exist = false
    for %%a in (%*) do (
        if  %%~xf == .%%a set exist = true
        if  %%~xf == .sys set exist = true
    )
    if  %exist% == false ( 
        del %%f
    )
)
pause
```

Would be very grateful for any suggestions on how to get this code working as expected by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your code is the variable expansion. In batch files, when a command or a block of commands (several commands enclosed in parenthesis) are readed, they are parsed and then executed. During the parse phase, the variable read operations (`%var%`) are removed from the code being replaced with the value inside the variable. Once this has been done, the command or block is executed.

All this means that when the code is executed, if you change a variable (`exists` in your code), the changed value can not be retrieved while inside the same command/block, as there is not any variable read operation, only the value in the variable before starting the execute phase.

This can be avoided using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. This command allows you to change where needed the syntax used to read a variable from `%var%` into `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the variable expansion must be delayed until the command is executed, not during parse phase.

So, your code could be something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cls
    cd test
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
        set "exist=false"
        for %%a in (%*) do (
            if /i "%%~xf" == ".%%a" set "exist=true"
            if /i "%%~xf" == ".sys" set "exist=true"
        )
        if  "!exist!"=="false" ( 
            del "%%f"
        )
    )
    pause
```

Note that

- `set var = value` has been changed into `set var=value`. Spaces are important, you were defining a variable called `var[space]` with a value `[space]value`
- all the variable assignments are quoted to prevent unneeded ending spaces included in the variable value. If spaces are included, the `==` test could fail. Being careful this is not needed, but it is a good habit.
- quotes are being included to prevent problems with spaces in file names or extensions
- the `%exists%` has been changed to `!exists!` so the changed value can be retrieved while inside the same block (`for %%f`)
- the `if` extension comparisons include the `/i` switch for case insensitive tests.

You should also note that when having delayed expansion enabled, the `!` character becomes a problem as the parser will see it as part of a variable read operation. If you have files or extensions that could include this character, delayed expansion is a problem. It can be done but requires to only enable delayed expansion when really needed and disable again when not required.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    cls
    cd test
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
        set "exist=false"
        for %%a in (%*) do (
            if /i "%%~xf" == ".%%a" set "exist=true"
            if /i "%%~xf" == ".sys" set "exist=true"
        )
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if  "!exist!"=="false" ( 
            endlocal
            del "%%f"
        ) else (
            endlocal 
        )
    )
    pause
```

But, as in your case you are only changing the variable value between two values and the values are irrelevant, it is only a flag, you can ignore delayed expansion and the real value inside the variable and use an alternative syntax, `if defined` to test if the variable contains or not a value. Your `true/false` can be a `defined/not defined` test

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    cd test
    for %%f in (*) do (
        set "removeFile=1"
        for %%x in (sys %*) do (
            if /i "%%~xf"==".%%~x" set "removeFile="
        )
        if defined removeFile del "%%f"
    ) 
    pause
```

If the extension matches any of the arguments, the variable content is removed, that is, now the variable is undefined.

**edit** to adapt to Magoo's comments

When dealing with the filesytem elements, it is possible to see unexpected behaviours in the file/folders selection.

Files and folders that don't follow the `8.3` traditional naming (up to 8 characters for the name, up to 3 for the extensions, no special characters, no spaces) have what is known as a long name, but they also have a short `8.3` name associated to the long name. It can be seen using the `/x` switch in the `dir` command.

While not directly visible, these short names are checked when a wildcard search is done, resulting in files/folders selected with long file names or extensions not matching the requested wildcard expresion but with short names or extensions that do match the wildcard.

In case the short names or extensions needs to be processed inside `for` loops, the modifiers used in `for` replaceable parameters (ex. `%%f`) to retrieve them are

```
%%~snxf    Short name and short extension of the element being referenced by %%f
%%~snf     Short name of the element being referenced by %%f
%%~sxf     Short extension of the element being referenced by %%f
```

Comment: Very good indeed. Perhaps however you should add a cautionary note about lfn vs sfn.

Comment: @Magoo, as is, the code has not any problem with short file names/extensions. The search is not done using the extension of the files and the `%%~xf` will retrieve the long extension if it exists.

Comment: Certainly - but it's a matter of user-expectation. Having deleted the required files, a user may then try `dir *.abc` for instance, having specified that `abc` be deleted by omitting it from the list to be retained in the parameters. A file that has a short extent of `.abc` would then be unexpectedly revealed. Equally, a file with a short extent of `.sys` may be unexpectedly deleted if its long extent was not one from the parameter-list. For example, `RANDOM~1.DPR = randomexp.dpr` and `RANDOM~2.DPR = randomexp.dproj` - specifying `dpr` to be retained would not save `random~2.dpr`

Comment: @Magoo, a file with a `.abc` short extension is not shown with `.abc` short extension unless you specifically request to see short names (meaning you are somehow aware of the situation). Users expect the code to behave according to what they see. Anyway, I've included a note, warning future readers of the possible problem. Thank you.